# Initializing const member within class declaration in C++

Tags: c++, g++

In PHP and C# the constants can be initialized as they are declared:

```
class Calendar3
{
    const int value1 = 12;
    const double value2 = 0.001;
}
```

I have the following C++ declaration of a functor which is used with another class to compare two math vectors:

```
struct equal_vec
{
    bool operator() (const Vector3D& a, const Vector3D& b) const
    {
        Vector3D dist = b - a;
        return ( dist.length2() <= tolerance );
    }

    static const float tolerance = 0.001;
};
```

This code compiled without problems with g++. Now in C++0x mode (-std=c++0x) the g++ compiler outputs an error message:

> error: ‘constexpr’ needed for in-class initialization of static data member ‘tolerance’ of non-integral type

I know I can define and initialize this `static const` member outside of the class definition. Also, a non-static constant data member can be initialized in the initializer list of a constructor.

But is there any way to initialize a constant within class declaration just like it is possible in PHP or C#?

#### Update

I used `static` keyword just because it was possible to initialize such constants within the class declaration in g++. I just need a way to initialize a constant in a class declaration no matter if it declared as `static` or not.

Comment: `I used static keyword just because it was possible to initialize such constants within the class declaration in g++. I just need a way to initialize a constant in a class declaration no matter if it declared as static or not.` That's the _wrong_ way to decide whether a member should be `static` or not. Never let lexical laziness decide the semantics of your code.

Comment: `That's the wrong way to decide whether a member should be static or not.` I don't agree. I think that does not matter for constant members.

Comment: @expresso: Not at all. You can initialise a non-`static` constant member with instance-specific information. That you've decided that your constant is a property of the type rather than of a specific instance is the reason to make it `static`, not because you fancied a typing shortcut.

Comment: @lightless: Well, it is possible, but I don't see any reason for making use of initialization of same instance-specific constants with different values. I used to use non-const class fields for that!

Comment: Why, if they never change after object instantiation? `struct myType { const std::time_t instantiated; myType() : instantiated(std::time(0)) {} };` Everything that _can_ be `const` *should* be `const`; that applies to `static` and non-`static` members alike.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

In C++11, non-`static` data members, `static constexpr` data members, and `static const` data members of integral or enumeration type may be initialized in the class declaration. e.g.

```
struct X {
    int i=5;
    const float f=3.12f;
    static const int j=42;
    static constexpr float g=9.5f;
};
```

In this case, the `i` member of all instances of class `X` is initialized to `5` by the compiler-generated constructor, and the `f` member is initialized to `3.12`. The `static const` data member `j` is initialized to `42`, and the `static constexpr` data member `g` is initialized to `9.5`.

Since `float` and `double` are not of integral or enumeration type, such members must either be `constexpr`, or non-`static` in order for the initializer in the class definition to be permitted.

Prior to C++11, only `static const` data members of integral or enumeration type could have initializers in the class definition.

Comment: Is there a link to the part of the standard where this was spec'd? I've just started using it (albeit compiling as C++14) and am delighted that it works, as I stand to save a lot of time by having the compiler do this for me. However, until reading your answer, I wasn't sure whether it _should_ be working! An official word would aid my confidence, haha. Fwiw I have it working with members like `char const n[3]{'a', 'b', 'c'};` too.

Comment: I wonder why `static const int` but `static constexpr float`? what does it mean `float and double are not of integral or enumeration type` ?

Comment: @mrgloom : yes, float and double are not.
If the datatype could be translated to a whole number, then it's an integral type.

Comment: What is the point of this restriction? In any case, thanks for the good answer

Answer (score 50):

Initializing static member variables other than const int types is not standard C++ prior C++11. The gcc compiler will not warn you about this (and produce useful code nonetheless) unless you specify the `-pedantic` option. You then should get an error similiar to:

```
const.cpp:3:36: error: floating-point literal cannot appear in a constant-expression
const.cpp:3:36: warning: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member constant ‘tolerance’ of non-integral type ‘const float’ [-pedantic]
```

The reason for this is that the C++ standard does not specifiy how floating point should be implemented and is left to the processor. To get around this and other limitations `constexpr` was introduced.

Comment: Thanks for the hint "is left to the processor". That made me thinking from "WTF is the technical difference regarding initialization between uint32_t and float?!?!?" to "Ah, ok!" :-D

Answer (score 15):

Yes. Just add the `constexpr` keyword as the error says.

Comment: Maybe he doesn't want to require C++11 for his project?

Comment: The issue he mentions was introduced due to the fact he tried to compile as C++11, i.e. he would like support C++11 :)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into real problems with this, because I need the same code to compile with differing versions of g++ (the GNU C++ compiler). So I had to use a macro to see which version of the compiler was being used, and then act accordingly, like so

```
#if __GNUC__ > 5
 #define GNU_CONST_STATIC_FLOAT_DECLARATION constexpr
#else
 #define GNU_CONST_STATIC_FLOAT_DECLARATION const
#endif

GNU_CONST_STATIC_FLOAT_DECLARATION static double yugeNum=5.0;
```

This will use 'const' for everything before g++ version 6.0.0 and then use 'constexpr' for g++ version 6.0.0 and above. That's a *guess* at the version where the change takes place, because frankly I didn't notice this until g++ version 6.2.1. To do it right you may have to look at the minor version and patch number of g++, so see

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html

for the details on the available macros.

With gnu, you could also stick with using 'const' everywhere and then compile with the `-fpermissive` flag, but that gives warnings and I like my stuff to compile cleanly.

Not great, because it's specific to gnu compilers, butI suspect you could do similar with other compilers.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need it in the one method you can declare it locally static:

```
struct equal_vec
{
    bool operator() (const Vector3D& a, const Vector3D& b) const
    {
        static const float tolerance = 0.001f;
        Vector3D dist = b - a;
        return ( dist.length2() <= tolerance );
    }
};
```