# C++ member variable semantics

Tags: java, c++

I have a rather simple question with an inkling as to what the answer is.

My generalized question:
What is actually going on when you declare a member variable, be it public or private, and for all permutations of variable types, e.g. static vs const vs regular variables?

```
class some_class
{
private:
    static const std::string str;
public:
...
}
```

I have kind of realized that in C++ there is no notion of a non-variable, that is, a non-constructed variable as I was kind of taught to believe exists with languages like Java. The same may also be true in Java, however it is not the way I was taught to think of things so I'm trying to come up with the correct way to think of these non-initialized variables.

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str; // A kind of non-variable, or non-constructed variable (refers to null).
        str = new String(); // Now this variable actually refers to an object rather than null, it is a constructed variable.
    }
}
```

Since C++ allows you to initialize member variables in the constructor through initializer lists, and I have proven to myself via use of a debugger that the variable doesn't exist before it is initialized through the initializer list (either explicitly or by default), what is, then, actually going on behind the scenes when you declare the member variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky question -- it's ambiguous depending on perspective.

From a pseudo-machine perspective, normally adding a non-static plain old data type to a class makes that class type bigger. The compiler also figures out how to align it and relative memory offsets to address it relative to the object in the resulting machine code.

This is pseudo-machine level because at the machine level, data types don't actually exist: just raw bits and bytes, registers, instructions, things like that.

When you add a non-primitive user-defined type, this recurses and the compiler generates the instructions to access the members of the member and so on.

From a higher level, adding members to a class makes the member accessible from instances (objects) of the class. The constructor initializes those members, and the destructor destroys them (recursively triggering destructors of members that have non-trivial destructors, and likewise for constructors in the construction phase).

Yet your example is a static member. For static members, they get stored in a data segment at the machine level and the compiler generates the code to access those static members from the data segment.

Some of this might be a bit confusing. C++ shares its legacy with C which is a hardware-level language, and its static compilation and linking affects its design. So while it can go pretty high-level, a lot of its constructs are still tied to how the hardware, compiler, and linker does things, whereas in Java, the language can make some more sensible choices in favor of programmer convenience without a language design that somewhat reflects all of these things.

Comment: But the declaration itself, in C++ doesn't count as a constructed object and doesn't exist until you explicitly construct it (either statically or through an initializer list) in a definition, correct? So in C++ there is no such thing as a simple, non-constructed variable; every variable is a constructed object (constructed at the very least via a default constructor)?

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera: With the exception of references.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera That's true in Java as well, I believe. Even though it lets you syntactically initialize members of a class outside of a constructor, they too do not exist until an instance of that class is created.

Comment: @Ike This is what confuses a lot of people, I think with C++, because C++ allows you to inline functions into declarations, but variables can't be inlined, because they don't exist until runtime in a definition, am I correct in this respect?

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera In C++11 you can actually initialize members directly in the class definition, albeit with some caveats.

Comment: @Ike do you have a reference to material on this inline initialization? Would like to learn a bit more about it. Thanks for your answer btw. Thought my post would get closed or downvoted by people too lazy to read, misinterpreting the question due to its simple-sounding nature. :)

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera A lot of this somewhat tricky stuff has to do with static compilation nature of C++ and its ties to the hardware. It's not a language that truly abstracts away those two details, so you kind of have to understand the nature of the compiler and linker and hardware the language design somewhat reflects. I'd recommend just generally starting with computer architecture and then progressing to, say, the dragon book (Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools), then maybe Stroustrup on the design of the C++ language.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera One thing that might clarify things is that regardless of the syntax, in Java or in C++, whether you initialize variables in a constructor or conveniently and directly in a class definition, non-statics don't exist in memory until an instance of that class is instantiated. If it's directly in the class definition, you can think of it like the language/compiler doing the extra work for you to generate the "constructor code". All of this boils down to similar machine code, and it's basically a matter of convenience.

Comment: @Ike apparently this is true for statics as well in C++, unless the code I posted in my question actually initializes the `std::string` using its default constructor, and I then re-initialize it using a different string object in my definition by using `const std::string some_class::str("foo");`, causing it to be initialized twice.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera That too is something that becomes a bit less weird when you understand the inner workings of the compiler and linker. In C++, when you declare a static member, it's not actually defined yet. You have to then define it. Put crudely, it's because when you add a static member, you are basically teaching the compiler a 'symbol' to look up. Other compilation units see the symbol, but it's up to the linker to take the symbol and the definition and put it all together so that the appropriate code to define (and possibly initialize) the static can be linked together.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera It's similar to how you need that header file/source file distinction in C++. The header file tells those including it what the symbols are and how they need to be accessed. They don't see the code in a cpp source file, crudely speaking. So the header teaches what the symbols are and what the rules are to access them so that the compiler can check for some errors. The source file then provides more information, and the linker hooks all this stuff up and gives you the final result.

Comment: @Ike Yeah, the reason I asked is because in the case of a templated class, typically functions are written inline to the definition, since to compile templates, the compiler requires both the declaration and definition at once anyways. However, I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to "inline" static member variables in this case.

Comment: The answer to which I read [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697265/static-const-double-cannot-have-an-in-class-initializer-why-is-it-so)
For anybody who reads this in the future. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

A variable of class type in Java is *really* a pointer. Unlike C and C++ pointers, it doesn't support pointer arithmetic (but that's not essential to being a pointer--for example, pointers in Pascal didn't support arithmetic either).

So, when you define a variable of class type in Java: `String str;`, it's pretty much equivalent to defining a pointer in C++: `String *str;`. You can then assign a new (or existing) String object to that, as you've shown.

Now, it's certainly *possible* to achieve roughly the same effect in C++ by explicitly using a pointer (or reference). There are differences though. If you use a pointer, you have to explicitly dereference that pointer to get the object to which it refers. If you use a reference, you *must* initialize the reference--and once you do so, that reference can never refer to any object other than the one with which it was initialized.

There are also some special rules for `const` variables in C++. In many cases, where you're just defining a symbolic name for a value:

```
static const int size = 1234;
```

...and you never use that variable in a way that requires it to have an address (e.g., taking its address), it usually won't be assigned an address at all. In other words, the compiler will know the value you've associated with that name, but when compilation is finished, the compiler will have substituted the value anywhere you've used that name, so the variable (as such) basically disappears (though if you have the compiler generate debugging information, it'll usually retain enough to know and display its name/type correctly).

C++ does have one other case where a variable is a *little* like a Java "zombie" object that's been declared but not initialized. If you move from an object: `object x = std::move(y);`, after the move is complete the source of the move (`y` in this case) can be in a rather strange state where it exists, but *about* all you can really do with it is assign a new value to it. Just for example, in the case of a string, it *might* be an empty string--but it also *could* retain exactly the value it had before the move, or it *could* contain some other value (e.g., the value that the destination string held before the move).

Even that, however, is a little bit different--even though you don't *know* its state, it's still an object that should maintain the invariants of its class--for example, if you move from a string, and then ask for the string's length, that length should match up with what the string actually contains--if (for example) you print it out, you don't know what string will print out, but you should *not* get an equivalent of a `NullPointerException`--if it's an empty string, it just won't print anything out. If it's a non-empty string, the length of the data that's printed out should match up with what its `.size()` indicates, and so on.

The other obviously similar C++ type would be a pointer. An uninitialized pointer does not point to an object. The pointer *itself* exists though--it just doesn't refer to anything. Attempting to dereference it could give some sort of error message telling you that you've attempted to use a null pointer--but unless it has static storage duration, or you've explicitly initialized it, there's no guarantee that it'll be a null pointer either--attempting to dereference it could give a garbage value, throw an exception, or almost anything else (i.e., it's undefined behavior).

Comment: Fantastic, and very thorough reponse. I like how you gave a higher-level overview while ike gave a lower level look into the compiler/linker semantics. I really wish I could mark both as answers :)